# Efficient way to rank up search results using inverted index

Tags: performance, algorithm, search-engine

My inverted index is like this:

> token_word | docid,position;docid,position;docid,position;

In the algorithm, in order to rank up when they query phrases, i open the bucket data of every word, then lookout for consecutive position matches, that will rank higher, is just a simple relevance ranking.
The problem is, i need to check, ALL the results in the algorithm in order to sort by the "rank score", even if i only show 10 per page.

Anyone know a way to solve that? Maybe i need to rankup docid's in the index itself?

Answer (score 4):

In addition of a `token_word | docid,position;docid,position;docid,position;` approach, I suggest you add a `token_word | docid,frequency;docid,frequency;docid,frequency;` record.

This way, you only have to consider a document once while responding to a query. This may increase preprocessing, but decrease useless overhead when a user queries.

You may have a problem dealing with multiple word queries (i.e. almost *all* queries), so take the `docid,position` approach for *some* results that are close or in a tie.

What I would do if I was in your position: Since you are showing 10 results per page, I would index all the documents according to frequency, and then index only the first 10 for the first page according to position. Then do the same for the second page if the user moves there.

---

A flaw in this approach is that sometimes the first few results on page *n + 1* may turn out to be better than the last few on page *n*.